# Were the moderators flagged by this user's "minor" edits? Did they find it irritating?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing, flagging

The question [Who did I irritate enough for someone to mass downvote some of my answers?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1316/12102) has a few answers, and discussion in comments under [one of them](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1317/12102) suggest that the user's edits could be "incredibly annoying", and later that:

> ...(minor edits) annoy most moderators, because it causes more work. The flag count goes way up, folks leave comments complaining, and we get emails sometimes as folks get so annoyed they spend the effort to go and find them out.

**Question:** Have @ReactingToAngularVues "minor" edits resulted in flags that the moderators have needed to take time to respond to, and have the mods been thusly irritated by it?

Comment: It hasn't been a problem here, though that's not really Rory's point.

Comment: Thanks @called2voyage - I think my comments got a bit out of hand under that one. My initial point was just to show how people could be annoyed - not to say that I am aware of that on this specific site. I think I worded things badly in the ongoing discussion - which was more about the network as a whole. If you want to move it to a chat I'd be perfectly okay with that