# Downvoters targeting users

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

Over the last few days I have noticed that many high voted questions and answers have been randomly downvoted. Even high voted questions and answers from me have been downvoted. I think it is from one user because when it happens, it happens within a minute or so.

[image]

This has happened more than once and I wanted to ask if other users here also noticed this and if something could be done. Usually when a user gives lot of votes within a short period of time it says [Voting corrected](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), but this particular user is not downvoting enough questions in a single day so that this system gets activated.

Here are some of the high voted questions which randomly got downvoted:

- [Why was there a minimum height for astronauts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/61515/why-was-there-a-minimum-height-for-astronauts)
- [Why are only 2 out of the 3 boosters on Falcon Heavy reused?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/60835/why-are-only-2-out-of-the-3-boosters-on-falcon-heavy-reused)
- [What is SpaceX doing differently with Starship to avoid it exploding like the N1?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/61621/what-is-spacex-doing-differently-with-starship-to-avoid-it-exploding-like-the-n1)
- [Why did the Soviet Union decide to use 33 small engines instead of a few large ones on the N1?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/61609/why-did-the-soviet-union-decide-to-use-33-small-engines-instead-of-a-few-large-o)
- [Were any of the Apollo astronauts smokers and did that cause any problems?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/61608/were-any-of-the-apollo-astronauts-smokers-and-did-that-cause-any-problems)

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing mods can do about this unless it's enough to hit the suspicious voting patterns threshold, because votes are anonymous. I can flag this for review by SE staff and see if there's anything they can do.

Comment: This appears to be happenign to me too, my top 5 questions all have downvotes except for one. My top answer does as well. All done within the past few weeks and many happened after i got into an arguement with TheMatrix Equation-balance

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch I did notice the argument going on with TheMatrix Equation-balance. However, if you go to his profil and click on reputation you can see that he did not cast the downvotes because he would have lost 1 reputation for each downvote if he did cast one.

Comment: How about the questons @TheRocketfan

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch he did recieve downvotes on his questions, but he didn’t cast many downvotes as far as I can tell.

Comment: @called2voyage how often does it have to happen to hit the suspicious voting patterns threshold. It has happened today too and I am expecting to happen again.

Comment: I am getting 3 or so downvotes on my questions mainly every day (always one of my top questions). It is annoying and clearly targeted voting. Unfortunately, I think the number is 5. @TheRocketfan

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch I feel like some fishy things are happening these days on space SE. Maybe the mods can have a look.

Comment: Yep. @TheRocketfan

Comment: It has to be at least 5 votes from a single user where at least 20% of their votes over at most the past year are targeted toward a single person.

Comment: not the first time this has been brought up: [Who did I irritate enough for someone to mass downvote some of my answers?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1316/who-did-i-irritate-enough-for-someone-to-mass-downvote-some-of-my-answers)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. I will be checking this out but unfortunately due to privacy concerns, I won't be able to identify *who* is doing it publically. But I will work with the mods to come to a resolution.

Comment: Ok, that is good to know.

Comment: Thank you. Will you also be able to reverse the votes? @Bella_Blue Bella_

Comment: Yesterday I saw Serial voting correct and saw that many of those questions which I listed now had their downvotes removed. Thank you for taking some action.

Answer (score 2):

> Usually when a user gives lot of votes within a short period of time it says Voting corrected, but this particular user is not downvoting enough questions in a single day so that this system gets activated.

That's an issue with the way Stack Exchange currently handles targeted serial downvoting: targeted serial downvoting is typically only considered when happening on the same day. If the targeted serial downvoting is performed during a longer timeframe (days/weeks/months/etc.), nothing is done.

Here is the feature request on Meta SE: [Be more proactive when a user continuously downvotes another user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355329/178179)

Comment: that is an issue

Comment: @TheRocketfan SE is overall not a friendly place towards people asking questions.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt everyone's experience will differ, but I do know what you mean. Perhaps "friendly" *proper* is too high a bar for SE - we're encouraged, and encourage each other to be welcoming to new users, but after a while we question-askers have to find a way to "make peace" or at least "find our place" with a given community, or give up on it. There's a few I have never been able to get any traction in. To me it feels like it's a "you're not one of us, you don't think the way we do" situation, but I would guess that users there would find a different wallpaper to cover it with :-)

Comment: "few" doesn't include this site; perhaps I've actually had *too much* traction here ;-)

Comment: @uhoh true, I'd be happy if it was neutral. But we're far from it. I wonder how the answerers would feel if we removed their answers if score=0 or less after a while.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt ha! I'd never thought about it like that. Hmm... maybe that's not a good thing, ya. I don't see it as unfriendly necessarily; starting from a blank sheet of paper developing SE must have been quite a challenge. At least they bumped the delta-reputataion per up vote from +5 to +10 to match answers a few years ago and now at least we are allowed to see our own roombad questions, but ya I don't see why they need to fade into oblivion or be [sent to the "corfnield" just because they didn't get any attention for a while.

Comment: ([cornfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Good_Life_(The_Twilight_Zone)#Plot_summary:~:text=since%20he%20banishes%20anyone%20thinking%20unhappy%20thoughts%20into%20the%20otherworldly%20cornfield%20from%20which%20there%20is%20no%20return))

Comment: @uhoh: A [question about the cornfield](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/202697/102339), on one of the more cliquish SE sites.

Comment: @DrSheldon ah thanks! That's definitely the link I should have used. :-) Now I've left an additional answer there. I never felt part of a clique there - the community seems incredibly accepting except for Valorum who used to try to close a lot of my "is there a  story about" questions.